# using thread in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a database in my application and I want to retrieve some information from database. I use this code ( this code works correctly ) but I want to write these code via `Thread`. How can I change my code?

```
public StructNameImage Open_Tbl_Plants(Context context_t, final String SQL_CODE) {
    Is_Exist_Database();
    open();
    cursor = mydb.rawQuery(SQL_CODE, null);
    StructNameImage ni = new StructNameImage();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        ni.Str_NameFa.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Name")));
        ni.Str_Image.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Image")));
    }
    cursor.close();
    return ni;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Loader](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html).
Loaders doing there work in Async in another Thread.

Looking at your Code Sample, there is no simple Way to add a Thread to make it Async.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your method from multiple thread *concurrently* if you use database connection pooler.

Concurrency can't be achieved within your function: only one thread can make query. And you can't access result set from multiple places as it's iterator.